# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am running fb prophet model to forecast a time series. The properties of input data frame is as below:

```
 0   ds      1924 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   y       1924 non-null   float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
```

when I try to fit model:

```
#FB_Prophet Model
#split dataset to train and test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_fb, test_fb= train_test_split(df_fb, test_size=0.20, shuffle= False)
model_fb= Prophet()
model.fit(test_fb)
```

I get this Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10200\2228570394.py in <module>
      4 train_fb, test_fb= train_test_split(df_fb, test_size=0.20, shuffle= False)
      5 model_fb= Prophet()
----> 6 model.fit(test_fb)
      7 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima\model.py in fit(self, start_params, transformed, includes_fixed, method, method_kwargs, gls, gls_kwargs, cov_type, cov_kwds, return_params, low_memory)
    388                 method_kwargs.setdefault('disp', 0)
    389 
--> 390                 res = super().fit(
    391                     return_params=return_params, low_memory=low_memory,
    392                     cov_type=cov_type, cov_kwds=cov_kwds, **method_kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py in fit(self, start_params, transformed, includes_fixed, cov_type, cov_kwds, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, return_params, optim_score, optim_complex_step, optim_hessian, flags, low_memory, **kwargs)
    672         # Unconstrain the starting parameters
    673         if transformed:
--> 674             start_params = self.untransform_params(start_params)
    675 
    676         # Remove any fixed parameters

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\sarimax.py in untransform_params(self, constrained)
   1434             if self.enforce_stationarity:
   1435                 unconstrained[start:end] = (
-> 1436                     unconstrain_stationary_univariate(constrained[start:end])
   1437                 )
   1438             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\tools.py in unconstrain_stationary_univariate(constrained)
    531     n = constrained.shape[0]
    532     y = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=constrained.dtype)
--> 533     y[n-1:] = -constrained
    534     for k in range(n-1, 0, -1):
    535         for i in range(k):

TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'Timestamp'
```

any one knows what is the problem?

I double check the format from 'ds' column which must be in format of Pandas date: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS for a timestamp and every thing looks ok to me. Why did I get the above error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback message so we get all of the details?

Comment: The problem isn't the date format. The problem is that you can't negate a date. Your data has a date where a number is needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying I have edited my post and added complete traceback message